# Set Screensaver Programatically

Tags: bash, screensaver

I have searched for this, but can only find (old) fragments of information.. and nothing especially concrete for Big Sur or Monterey about how to set the screen saver through a script (bash most likely) ..

I simply want to set the screen saver to Arabesque, and the timeouts.. from my investigations different screen savers have their settings littered through out various different configs, and also there is a caching problem to overcome too..

Any links to documentation, or pointers much appreciated!

Comment: It is possible to do it in AppleScript, although such script is not very reliable, because it might break when new MacOSX version comes out. There are many AppleScript examples online for how to control various System Preferences options.

Comment: Another idea would be to figure where MacOSX stores screensaver information and timeouts and start from there

Comment: ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost.

Comment: @Gintaras locating where the info is stored is what i want to do, teach a guy how to fish, is there a utility to track down these config settings perhaps?

Comment: Mine is stored in that directory, a weird file named "com.apple.screensaver.WEIRD-UID.plist" I'm not sure where the UID comes from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running this following line of code in Terminal will set your current screensaver to "Arabesque" with a delay interval of 600 seconds.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set current screen saver to screen saver "Arabesque"' -e 'tell application "System Events" to set delay interval of screen saver preferences to 600 -- Number In Seconds'
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i came back to this question to post that i did ;)

Comment: now... on to the power saving settings :D